# Proper variety such that no complement of closed irreducible subset is affine

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral scheme. Assume there exists a proper morphism $X\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{C}$ of relative dimension $d>0$. Can we find a non-empty affine open subscheme with an irreducible complement?

If $d=1$, then the complement of a closed point is necessarily affine so we win.

Comment: possibly the paper "Affine Open Subsets of Algebraic Varieties and Ample Divisors" by Goodman is relevant.

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but given the different unregistered accounts you keep opening https://mathoverflow.net/users/140276/m-for-motive https://mathoverflow.net/users/140971/m-for-motive https://mathoverflow.net/users/140978/m-for-motive https://mathoverflow.net/users/140961/m-for-motive would it not make sense to register a single account?

Comment: Given your substantial history of ignoring comments and not acknowledging answers, I'm going to refrain from posting my answer to this one.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I don't understand your motivation. I think it is safe to assume that if you post an answer at least 50 people will see it within 3 days (probably twice as much). Out of these 50 people, only 1 is the OP, that is 2% of all people who would benefit from your answer. Is the sole reason you are withholding the answer is that the OP is being a jerk? Or do you want to get the reputation for an accepted answer? Not that there is anything wrong with that, just want to clarify.

Comment: To put things in context, assume the OP is a Martian who was connected to our Internet to halt the progress of science on Earth. If we react like that to their actions, they have kind of succeeded in their mission: because (a) if somebody else asks the same question, it will be closed as a duplicate (b) you do not want to post an answer because the OP is a jerk. So this piece of knowledge can not be disseminated via this channel.

Comment: @kartop_man When writing an answer, especially an expository answer for a newer mathematician, it can be helpful to imagine the specific person you are writing it for, rather than the abstract 50 other people who will probably read it. If you know that this person will never react, it could be disheartening. This at least explains why someone could be motivated, if not certifying the correctness of reacting this way.

Comment: @kartop_man If OP never accepts an answer it will cause some small trouble in the system - people looking for questions to answer will see it, while people looking for already answered questions might not, and the Community user will automatically keep bumping it up to the top. But I guess if you want more people to read your answer that would be a good thing.

Comment: @WillSawin what you say makes sense, didn't think of it this way.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome new contributor.  This follows by combining several results from Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*. Let $k$ be a field.

**Definition.** A closed subset $Z$ of a locally Noetherian scheme $X$ has **pure codimension** $\geq c$ **locally everywhere** if $\text{dim}_p(X) \geq c + \text{dim}_p(Z)$ for every point $p$ of $Z$.

**Proposition.** Every normal, finite type, separated $k$-scheme contains a quasi-projective open subscheme whose closed complement has codimension $\geq 2$ locally everywhere.

**Proof.**  Every normal scheme is a disjoint union of its irreducible components.  Hence it suffices to prove this for an *irreducible* scheme.  Let $X$ be such a scheme.  Denote the dimension by $d$.

Let $I$ be the set of ordered pairs $(U,U^o)$ of a nonempty open subscheme $U$ of $X$ and a quasi-projective open subscheme $U^o$ of $U$ whose complement has dimension $\leq d-2.$  This has a lexicographic partial order by set inclusion.  Every open affine subscheme of $X$ gives an element of $I$, so $I$ is not empty.  By the Noetherian hypothesis, there exists a maximal element of $I$, say $(U,U^o).$

By definition, there exists a locally closed immersion of $k$-schemes, $$i:U^o \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k.$$  By Zariski's Main Theorem, the maximal domain of definition of the rational transformation $i$ on $X$ is an open subscheme whose closed complement has dimension $\leq d-2$.  Thus, there exists a closed subset $Z$ of $X$ containing $U\setminus U^o$, having dimension $\leq d-2$, and such that $i$ is a regular morphism on $X\setminus Z$.

By way of contradiction, assume that the complement of $U$ is nonempty.  For any open affine $V$ of $X$ that intersects the complement, there exists a locally closed immersion of $k$-schemes, $$j:V\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m_k.$$ The maximal domain of definition of $j$ on $X$ is the open complement of a closed subset, say $Y$.  By Zariski's Main Theorem, $Y$ has dimension $\leq d-2$.

On the open complement $W$ of $Z\cup Y$, consider the product $k$-morphism, $$(i,j):W \to \mathbb{P}^n_k \times_{\text{Spec}\ k} \mathbb{P}^m_k.$$  Since the restriction of $i$ to $U^o\cap W$ is a locally closed immersion, also the restriction of $(i,j)$ to $U^o\cap W$ is a locally closed immersion.  Similarly, the restriction to $V\cap W$ is a locally closed immersion.  Thus, the restriction to $(U^o\cup V)\cap W$ is a locally closed immersion.  Since the Segre map is a closed immersion, it follows that $(U^o\cup V)\cap W$ is a quasi-projective $k$-scheme.

Thus, $(U\cup V,U^\cup V)$ is an element in $I$ that is strictly larger than $(U,U^o).$  This is a contradiction of maximality.  Therefore, by contradiction, $U$ equals $X$.  **QED**

**Corollary.** Every reduced, finite type, separated $k$-scheme contains a quasi-projective open subscheme whose closed complement has codimension $\geq 2$ locally everywhere.

**Proof.**  Let $X$ be a reduced, finite type, separated $k$-scheme.  Denote by $X_n$ the maximal open subscheme of $X$ that is normal.  Since $X$ is reduced, this is a dense open subscheme.

By the Noether Normalization Theorem, the normalization of $X$ is a finite morphism.  Denote this finite morphism by $$\nu:\widetilde{X}\to X.$$  By the proposition, there exists a quasi-projective open subscheme $\widetilde{X}^o$ of $\widetilde{X}$ whose complement has codimension $\geq 2$ locally everywhere.   Let $\widetilde{L}$ denote an ample invertible sheaf on $\widetilde{X}^o$.

Let $J$ denote the set of triples $(U,U^o,L_U,\phi)$ of an open subscheme $U$ of $X$ containing $X_n$, an open subscheme $U^o$ of $U$ contained in $\nu(\widetilde{X}^o)$ and whose complement $U\setminus U^o$ has codimension $\geq 2$ everywhere, an invertible sheaf $L_U$ on $U^o$, and an isomorphism $\phi$ from $\nu^*L_U$ to the restriction of $\widetilde{L}$ to $\nu^{-1}(U^o)$.  Since $\widetilde{L}$ is ample, also $\widetilde{L}^o$ is ample, cf. Exercise III.5.7(d) of Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*.  The set $J$ is partially ordered by lexicographic set inclusion followed by extension of invertible sheaves and isomorphisms.  Since $(X_n,X_n\cap \nu(\widetilde{X}^o),\nu_*\widetilde{L}|,\text{Id})$ is one element of $J$, the set $J$ is not empty.  By the Noetherian hypothesis, there exists a maximal triple $(U, U^o,L_U,\phi)$.

By way of contradiction, assume that $U$ does not equal $X$.  By maximality, the closed complement of $U$ has pure codimension $1$.  Thus, the closed image $\nu(\widetilde{X}\setminus \widetilde{X}^o)$ contains no irreducible component of the complement of $U$.  Let $p$ be a generic point of the complement of $U$.  Thus, $p$ is not contained in $\nu(\widetilde{X}\setminus \widetilde{X}^o)$.

Since every invertible sheaf on Spec of a semilocal Noetherian ring is free, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ contained in $\nu(\widetilde{X}^o)$ such that the restriction of $\widetilde{L}^o$ to $\nu^{-1}(V)$ is free.  Up to shrinking $V$, we may assume that $U^o\cap V$ is contained in the normal locus $X_n$.

Define $L_V$ to be the structure sheaf on $V$.  Define $\psi$ to be an isomorphism of the pullback of $L_V$ and the restriction of $\widetilde{L}$ to $\nu^{-1}(V)$.  Since $U\cap V$ is contained in the normal locus of $X$, there is a unique isomorphism of the restrictions of $L_V$ and $L_U$ to $U\cap V$ compatible with $\phi$ and $\psi$.  Thus, by glueing, there is a triple of $J$ whose open subsets are $(U\cup V, U^o\cup V)$.  This contradicts maximality of $(U,U^o,L_U,\phi)$.  Therefore, by contradiction, $U$ equals $X$.  Finally, by Theorem II.7.6 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*, the open subscheme $U^o$ is quasi-projective.  **QED**

**Theorem.**  Every finite type, separated $k$-scheme contains a quasi-projective open subscheme whose closed complement has codimension $\geq 2$ locally everywhere.

**Proof.**  For any two irreducible components of unequal dimension, say $d<e$, every irreducible component of the intersection is a proper subvariety of each irreducible component.  Thus, the dimension of the intersection is $\leq d-1$.  Since the dimension of the whole scheme is $\geq e$ at each point of the intersection, the intersection has codimension $\geq 2$ locally everywhere.  Thus, without loss of generality, remove the intersection of any two irreducible components of unequal dimension so that every connected component of the scheme has pure dimension.  Since the scheme is the disjoint union of its connected components, it suffices to prove the result for a connected scheme of pure dimension $d$.

By the previous corollary, the reduced locus contains an open subscheme whose closed complement has codimension $\geq 2$ locally everywhere and that supports an ample invertible sheaf.  This quasi-projective open contains a quasi-projective open as above that is a union of two open affine subschemes.  The intersection of these open affine subschemes is also affine, since the scheme is separated.

By Exercise III.4.2 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*, each of these open affines in the reduced scheme is the intersection of the reduced scheme with an open affine of the original scheme.  By Exercise III.4.6 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*, the ample invertible sheaf extends to each of these open affines in the original scheme.  Also, the glueing isomorphism of these invertible sheaves on the intersection open affine of the reduced scheme extends to a morphism of coherent sheaves on the intersection open affine of the original scheme.  By Nakayama's Lemma, since this morphism restricts to an isomorphism on the reduced scheme, this morphism is an isomorphism.  Thus, by glueing, there is an invertible sheaf on the union of these two open affines whose restriction to the reduced scheme is the original ample invertible sheaf.

Applying Exercise III.5.7(d) once more, this invertible sheaf on the union of the two open affines is an ample invertible sheaf.  Thus, the union of the two open affines in the original scheme is quasi-projective by Theorem II.7.6 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry*. **QED**

Finally, let $X$ be an integral, finite type, separated $k$-scheme of dimension $d$.  As in the corollary, let $X^o$ be an open subscheme of $X$ that is quasi-projective and whose closed complement has dimension $\leq d-2$.  By Bertini's Theorem, for a sufficiently ample Veronese re-embedding of $X^o$, there exists an irreducible hyperplane section of $X^o$ whose complement is an affine open $U$ of $X^o$.  The complement of $X^o$ in $X$ has dimension $\leq d-2$ , yet every irreducible component of $X\setminus U$ has dimension $d-1$ (**ed.** this holds by Corollaire 21.12.7 of EGA IV, as noted by @kartop_man below).  Thus, the open subset $X^o\setminus U$ of $X\setminus U$ is a dense open subset.  Therefore, also $X\setminus U$ is irreducible.

Comment: in the last paragraph, are you using the fact that in a Noetherian separated scheme, each irreducible component of the complement of a non-empty affine open subscheme has codimension $\leq 1$? I think the reference is EGA IV, Corollaire 21.12.7, maybe include that for completeness.

Comment: @kartop_man  Thank you for the reference.  I added it.  Also I remembered after posting that sometimes the bounty forces reputation points on the answerer.  I prefer not to collect reputation points.  If you, or anybody else, would prefer to post an answer (maybe just the answer above), that would be great.  That way I can avoid the reputation points.

Comment: Oh no . . . too late.

Comment: See also Gross, "The resolution property of algebraic surfaces", [link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/resolution-property-of-algebraic-surfaces/9DDF803596FD32B1D848E25F91B44376), Theorem 1.5, where the theorem is proved over an arbitrary excellent base ring.

Comment: @MinseonShin which theorem is proved? I see the one about thick neighbourhoods, but Jason Starr is also relying on a Bertini-type statement to conclude. Can you show me a precise Bertini-type statement over a general excellent base ring?

Comment: Hi @kartop_man, I was only referring to the **Theorem** in Professor Starr's answer, not the original question by m_for_motive.

Comment: Either way, Professor Starr, assume we tell you that the statement marked as **Theorem** in your post holds not only over fields, but also over excellent rings (well, the paper of Gross above tells you that). Is there any way to answer the original question over excellent rings then?

Comment: @kartop_man  I believe that Minseon Shin knows as much or more about this area than I do.  Anyway, the Bertini theorem needed to complete the argument *might* follow from the article of Gabber-Liu-Lorenzini, "Hypersurfaces in projective schemes and a moving lemma".

Comment: I am also trying to understand your Bertini argument. First, if $k$ is finite, does your argument need some non-classical theorems (like https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4960)? If so, it might make sense to add a specific reference. Note that the linked reference requires geometric irreducibility, as opposed to irreducibility, which is not stated in your answer as an assumption as far as I can tell. See also the anti-Bertini theorem there, which might crush some more optimistic statements.

Comment: Second, if $X^o$ is not neither affine nor projective, for example if you take the affine plane minus a finite number of closed points, is it obvious that the hyperplane section provided to you by Bertini will have an affine complement? In that example, you would need the hyperplane section to pass through all of the punctured points. I think these two "issues" (they probably are not issues, but just my misunderstandings) could combine to yield something that requires some additional clarification.

Comment: The hyperplane section is parameterized by a point of the dual projective space whose residue field may be a proper field extension of the ground field.  The OP asks about "irreducibility", not about "geometric irreducibility".  Regarding the base locus, yes I am using the fact that a sufficiently ample hypersurface containing a fixed closed subscheme of an irreducible projective scheme is itself irreducible.  This is straightforward to prove by blowing up the closed subscheme and working with a "twist" of the pullback ample invertible sheaf by the exceptional divisor class.